# Unable to stop remove Event Listener from object

Tags: javascript

I have a very basic little "game" here. In the for loop that says  `i < miniSquares.length` (the last for loop in my JS code), there is an `addEventListener` that targets every object (the objects as `div`s in this case) with a class of `.miniSquare`. In the function executed by the `addEventListener` I stated at the end that I want to remove the `.miniSquare` class by typing `this.classList.remove("miniSquare")` so that the `EventListener` does not execute again. My logic is that if I remove the class that targets the `EventListener` there should be no way that the eve

```js
  const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
  let squares = [];



  function createBoard() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      const square = document.createElement('div');
      square.setAttribute("id", i);
      square.setAttribute("class", "miniSquare");
      grid.appendChild(square);
      squares.push(square);
    }
    const miniSquares = document.querySelectorAll(".miniSquare");


    for (let i = 0; i < miniSquares.length; i++) {
      miniSquares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        const minedArray = ["bitCoin", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock"];
        const minedRandomizer = minedArray[Math.floor(minedArray.length * Math.random())];
        this.setAttribute("class", minedRandomizer);
        this.classList.remove("miniSquare");
      });

    }
  }

  createBoard();
```

```css
.grid{
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: green;
  background-size: cover;
}

.miniSquare {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: brown;
  background-size: cover;
}

.rock{
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: grey;
    background-size: cover;
}

.bitCoin{
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: yellow;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bitcoin Mining</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="grid">

</div>


<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

nt listener would work on it again (basically I don't want the object to be clicked more than once, once it is clicked nothing shall happen if clicked again). Here is the code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the event handler in a named function and make it deregister itself using [removeEventListerner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener):

```
function onClick() {
  const minedArray = ["bitCoin", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock"];
  const minedRandomizer = minedArray[Math.floor(minedArray.length * Math.random())];
  this.setAttribute("class", minedRandomizer);
  this.classList.remove("miniSquare");
  this.removeEventListener("click", onClick)
}

for (let i = 0; i < miniSquares.length; i++) {
  miniSquares[i].addEventListener("click", onClick);
}
```

Comment: @antonku Will it help for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63189460/addeventlistener-event-calling-multiple-times

Comment: @VinodhKumarC Yes, this may help, I have posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

if you have attached an event handler to an elemenet, it needs to be removed specifically from the element. It does not matter what was the CSS selector you would have used to serach the element, and now the css selector is not applicable to the element.